# Where do I find username & password for newly installed 14.04 LTS

Tags: username

I have just installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS and it is asking for a username and password.  I don't have one.  What do I do please? ctrl alt delete does not work neither does ctrl alt t

Comment: It should have asked you for a name for the default user whilst you were installing, did that not happen?

Comment: During the installation you`ve been ask for a username and password.
The CTRL-ALT-DEL is only a shortcut for Windows

Comment: You can reset your Username and Password.
Try the following link.<br/>
http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/419117

Answer (score 1):

You can open up a terminal and use the command `whoami` to know your current username.

Once you know your user name you can follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/387996). This should reset your password and if you have any other problem please update your question according to it.

Comment: how if he can't login?

Comment: he can enter the root shell in recovery mode and enter the command `cat /etc/passwd`  and the login name should appear near the end of the result like `bose:x:1000:1000:BOSE,,,:/home/bose:/bin/bash` where bose is my username.

Comment: I don't think he knows the root password if he doesn't know his username and password

Comment: once he knows the username from the previous command, then he can reset the password, without ever knowing the current password